# Spring data jpa query string error

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to update address.

```
@Modifying
@Query("update UserInfo u set u.address = ?1 where u.username = ?2")
void setAddress(String address, String username);
```

But it doesn't work.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
|Exception Description: No transaction is currently active; nested exception is 
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: |Exception Description: No transaction 
is currently active
```

And it says my query string is an **unknown source**

Which reason occupy this exception?

How to update mutiple fields in an update Query?

```
@Query("update UserInfo u set u.address = ?1, u.phoneNumber = ?2 where u.username = ?3")
```

Answer (score 0):

No transaction is currently active, so just add an annotation to tell the spring, this is transaction

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("update UserInfo u set u.address = ?1 where u.username = ?2")
void setAddress(String address, String username);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a context as kind of below, you can change db and ORM vendor.Now you have transaction manager. Then use @Transactional annotation on your method.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpa.sample" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" />
```